# ES curl for email is not returning correct results despite knowing that it does exist

Tags: elasticsearch

I do a query for a term "owner" and a document showed the email for an owner.  I figured to look at all Houses which have this email, to query for email instead of owner.

When I do the following curl request, It doesnt return any actual cases.

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_search/?pretty" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d'{"query": {"match": {"email": {"query": "test.user@gmail.com"}}}}'
```

it does not return the correct information.  I wanted to find an exact result.  I was also thinking to use the term:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_search/?pretty" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d'{"query": {"term": {"email": "test.user@gmail.com"}}}'
```

in an attempt to find an exact match.  This seems to return no document information.  I am thinking that it might have something to do with the periods or maybe the *@* symbol.

I have also tried match when trying to wrap the email with escaped quotes, escaped periods.

Is there something going on I am unaware of with special characters?

Comment: What kind of mapping is defined for field email?

Comment: With Logstash, I have it categorized as:  `${DATA:email}` each message is defined as:  `"%{DATA:email}[;:]%{GREEDYDATA:metricdata}"`

Comment: Thank you fo the reply. With mapping I had the elasticsearch index mapping in mind - sorry for not being specific enough.

Comment: @ibexit how do i find this?  When dealing with fields, i didnt do anything with regards to it.  I only knew of defining types through the logstash grok capabilities etc.

Comment: Ok. Have a look at this:  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html and then issue a curl like this: GET /<index_name_goes_here>/_mapping

Comment: may i ask you to check if the solution below works for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch is not schema free, now they are calling it "schema on write" and that´s a very good name for the schema generation process. When elasticsearch recieves a new document with unknown fields, it tries an "educated guess".

When you index the first document with the field "email", elasticsearch will have a look on the value provided and create a mapping for this field.
The value "test.user@gmail.com" will then be mapped to "Text" mapping type.

Now, let´s see how elastic will process a simple document with a email. Create a document:

```
POST /auto_mapped_index/_doc
{"email": "nobody@example.com"}
```

Courious how the mapping look like? Here you go:

```
GET /auto_mapped_index/_mapping
```

Will be answered with:

```
{
  "my_first_index" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "email" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You see, the `"type" : "text"` is indicating the mapping type "text" as assumed before. And there is also a subfield "keyword", automatically created by elastic for text type fields by default.

We have 2 options now, the easy one is to query the keyword subfield (please note the dot notation):

```
GET /my_first_index/_search
{"query": {"term": {"email.keyword": "nobody@example.com"}}}
```

Done!

The other option is to create a specific mapping for our index. In order to do so, we need a new and empty index and define the mapping. We can do it with one shot:

```
PUT /my_second_index/
{
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "email" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now let us populate the index (here i´m putting two documents):

```
POST /my_second_index/_doc
{"email": "nobody@example.com"}

POST /my_second_index/_doc
{"email": "anybody@example.com"}
```

And now your unchanged query should work :

```
GET /my_second_index/_search
{"query": {"term": {"email": "anybody@example.com"}}}
```

Response:

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.2876821,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_second_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "OTf3n28BpmGM8iQdGR4j",
        "_score" : 0.2876821,
        "_source" : {
          "email" : "anybody@example.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This works. I did the curl request  with your query term keyword, and it worked, fairly quickly too!  This is fantastic, thank you.

Comment: I was suddently getting a data too large, data for [<http_request>] would be xxx, which is larger than the limit of YYYY, real usage: xxxx.   It worked for my first query, but I think that since the server is sharing ram between logstash and elasticsearch, it is having issues with elastic queries which require a certain overhead.  my jvm.options has -Xms2g and -Xmx2g, but i have 4g ram on a PI, so I am trying to keep 2 for logstash and 2 for elastic... i think?  I wasnt sure if this is specific to querying through and if there is a way to allocate less for searching.

Comment: Is this case insensitive?  is there a way to change the case?  I know case doesnt matter with the instance of emails.

Comment: Case sensivity is a matter of used analyser. If you need sth. different, defibe your own mapping with a amalyser fulfilling your requirements. Have a look on this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer.html

Comment: The rule of thumb is having the smae free space as you assigned to elasticsearch. There are also serveral other hints regarding the setup over here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/system-config.html

Comment: Ahh, good to know.  Im happy that  I  can do it on 1 machine, but it  does take away from respective processing powers. I may shortly be spinning up dedicated machines on the network, to help assist in this.

Comment: Is it better for performance reasons to change the index that email be a keyword? I am going through this problem as well.

Comment: @Snickers3192 it looks like to me, it was subjective.  You can augment it such that you can say `{"query": {"term": {"email": "anybody@example.com"}}}` but it seems that you can just as easily maintain it as: `{"query": {"term": {"email.keyword": "nobody@example.com"}}}`.  As noticed, the difference is: _email_ vs _email.keyword_ respectively.

Comment: @Snikers3192: It's not performance why you  need to change it. The reason is different processing by elasticsearch. Keyword fields are not analyzed while indexing and the value goes in the very same form into the lucene index as provided. Text fields are analyzed and the text is getting tokenized. That's why the search on keyword works different.

Comment: @Fallenreaper: The feature you are mentioning is called subfields. By default elasticsearch is creating a keyword subfield for each text field. But there are many cases, where such a default behavior is not desired. For example when you know, you'll never search in the parts of the value, and the only search case is treating the value as a whole keyword. Then having a text field because if the default mapoing is just a waste of disk and ram. On the other side, if you have a text value made if many wirds and sentences, having a keyword may be a waste too.